# Are two UPDATE statements in same BEGIN-END block executed at the exact same time?

Tags: c#, oracle

If I have a table as follows:

```
CID COLUMN1
1   Joe
2   John
```

And I run the following code below. Could a Select statement be executed (at some inopportune precise millisecond about half way through the running of my code) that would return COLUMN1 = John for BOTH rows in the table? Or would Oracle run both update statements in my code "together" so to speak, so this could NEVER happen.

```
string sqlStr = @"Begin
              Update TABLE1 set COLUMN1 = 'John' where CID = 1;
              Update TABLE1 set COLUMN1 = 'Joe' where CID = 2;
              End;";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oracle_connstr);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlStr, conn);
try
{
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
        if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
        if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-jan/o65asktom-082389.html

Comment: @DarkFalcon That is a long article with many technical terms I am not familiar with, but thanks. I will take a closer look.

Comment: `BEGIN-END` is an anonymous **PL/SQL** block. And PL/SQL is a procedural language, thus the two update statements together within `BEGIN-END` would be executed procedurally one after another as a single transaction. If the program fails, the entire transaction would be rolled back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two `UPDATE` statements will be run sequentially.  So the second `UPDATE` won't run until the first `UPDATE` finishes.

Assuming that the two statements are part of the same transaction (which they would be in this example), other sessions are prevented from reading the intermediate state where both rows have a value of "John" by the transaction isolation level.  Oracle does not allow dirty reads.  Normally, everything in Oracle runs in the read committed transaction isolation level.  That means that other sessions would see the values prior to your transaction starting until your transaction committed at which point both statements (and anything else that is part of the transaction) would be complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not only did you answer my question, but it was the answer I wanted! Accepted! (-- did I say it was fast too!)

Comment: Note that the behavior Justin describes has nothing to do with putting the two updates inside a PL/SQL block.  Two statements executed serially in the same Oracle session are always part of the same transaction (assuming that your client does not have autocommit enabled), and would be committed or rolled back as part of that transaction.  Putting both statements inside a block does mean, however, that if the block ends with an error, then all changes made in the block are rolled back as a unit.

Comment: @DaveCosta - Very true.  By default, though, the `OracleConnection` object would be in autocommit mode.  You'd have to add additional code to explicitly start and end a transaction in order to get "normal" Oracle transactional behavior

Comment: @DaveCosta - Thank you (and Justin Cave) for both of your additional comments. I have learned a lot more than I expected from my question. I will pass this info on to my C# programmer coworker as it very useful to understand these points.